# Suggested naming conventions for Selenium identifiers

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium page object model to define all the page elements. I am little unconvinced with the naming conventions that I have followed for naming the element and felt too long. Please suggest on this.

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//tbody[@id='tabview:listComp1_data']/tr/td[1]/div/div[2]")
public WebElement tableCompanyResultsRow;

@FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='mttAddId']")
public WebElement buttonAddMap;

@FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='ittAddId']")
public WebElement buttonAddItinerary;

@FindBy(xpath = "//div[@id='ajaxStatusPanel_start']/img")
public WebElement imageLoading;
```

Comment: you can use short notation like btn, lbl, img, tab, etc...

Comment: I am curious if the locator variable should start with a upper or lower case letter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have been using the below naming conventions for a long time and it helps understand and distinguish the UI elements.

For locators I always prefix `loc_` to the variable name. For example: `loc_btnExit`, etc.

```
+----------+----------------------------+--------+-----------------+
| Category |      UI/Control type       | Prefix |     Example     |
+----------+----------------------------+--------+-----------------+
| Basic    | Button                     | btn    | btnExit         |
| Basic    | Check box                  | chk    | chkReadOnly     |
| Basic    | Combo box                  | cbo    | cboEnglish      |
| Basic    | Common dialog              | dlg    | dlgFileOpen     |
| Basic    | Date picker                | dtp    | dtpPublished    |
| Basic    | Dropdown List / Select tag | ddl    | ddlCountry      |
| Basic    | Form                       | frm    | frmEntry        |
| Basic    | Frame                      | fra    | fraLanguage     |
| Basic    | Image                      | img    | imgIcon         |
| Basic    | Label                      | lbl    | lblHelpMessage  |
| Basic    | Links/Anchor Tags          | lnk    | lnkForgotPwd    |
| Basic    | List box                   | lst    | lstPolicyCodes  |
| Basic    | Menu                       | mnu    | mnuFileOpen     |
| Basic    | Radio button / group       | rdo    | rdoGender       |
| Basic    | RichTextBox                | rtf    | rtfReport       |
| Basic    | Table                      | tbl    | tblCustomer     |
| Basic    | TabStrip                   | tab    | tabOptions      |
| Basic    | Text Area                  | txa    | txaDescription  |
| Basic    | Text box                   | txt    | txtLastName     |
| Complex  | Chevron                    | chv    | chvProtocol     |
| Complex  | Data grid                  | dgd    | dgdTitles       |
| Complex  | Data list                  | dbl    | dblPublisher    |
| Complex  | Directory list box         | dir    | dirSource       |
| Complex  | Drive list box             | drv    | drvTarget       |
| Complex  | File list box              | fil    | filSource       |
| Complex  | Panel/Fieldset             | pnl    | pnlGroup        |
| Complex  | ProgressBar                | prg    | prgLoadFile     |
| Complex  | Slider                     | sld    | sldScale        |
| Complex  | Spinner                    | spn    | spnPages        |
| Complex  | StatusBar                  | sta    | staDateTime     |
| Complex  | Timer                      | tmr    | tmrAlarm        |
| Complex  | Toolbar                    | tlb    | tlbActions      |
| Complex  | TreeView                   | tre    | treOrganization |
+----------+----------------------------+--------+-----------------+
```

Comment: It is called Hungarian notation and it is outdated. DO NOT follow this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation